# Shared entity module with quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus

I am currently starting to build my first project with quarkus and I would like to know if the following architecture would make sense.

Let's say I have modules A and B which are simple JAX-RS Services built with quarkus-resteasy. Both of these modules use the same entities from module C.

Would it be a good idea to add quarkus-hibernate-orm to module C and then add this module as a dependency to module A and B?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of your domain model. For simple, flat entities or very flat aggregates in a simple CRUD scenario, using persistence entities upwards the REST controller might be a feasible solution. As soon as your domain model becomes more complex and implements more complex business logic than just managing CRUD logic, persistence entities will not longer fit the need of the domain model (and I assure, they will. If not sooner, then later ;-) ). Then, it's time to work with persistence entities only behind the repository interface. The repository then returns real domain entities which implement behavior instead of just providing accessors to internal state, like POJO's do. In such a case, I highly recommend to separate persistence entities from domain entities. The REST controller then deals with simple DTO's which an ApplicationService converts into domain entities using a factory, and forwards them to a Repository which turns them into persistence entities and uses the hibernate Session, or the JPA EntityManager to deal with the persistence infrastructure.